# Dead Keys Previews gone

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 with GNOME 3.36.3, using X11 and with IBus 1.5.22.

When using spanish keyboard, dead keys used to show a preview of the selected accent to use.
For example, I wanted to write "Camión", so I write Cami followed by pressing the ´ key and at that moment the screen would show a ´ with an underscore, showing me that the computer was waiting an input to complete the accented letter, so then I pressed "o" to form "ó". This is what I believe it's called Preedit Text.

But at some point it seems I installed something or did something in my computer that disabled this feature. And I checked that using my Live USB to use the Try Ubuntu mode and also Logging out of my session both showed me that the feature is still there. I have tried looking for some configuration related to that in dconf editor and around IBus but to no luck.

By using "ps aux | grep ibus" in terminal I could check that my /usr/libexec/ibus-ui-gtk3 daemon was not running, which I believe has something to do with the missing UI, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok so now I do believe it has to do with IBus Engine but I still don't know how to make it work again

Comment: Made an additional report to ibus github to get an additional answer from devs. https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2282

Comment: It will be important to indicate what Ubuntu version you use.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, here it is.

Ubuntu 20.04.1
GNOME 3.36.3
Using X11
IBus 1.5.22

Comment: Seems to be the Embed Preedit text of IBus but no idea what's making it go wrong

Comment: Use "edit" to add information to your question. Comments may disappear or may not be seen.

Comment: Sure I will do it

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution with the creator: https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2282

*gedit ~/.profile*

**and inserted:**

*export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus*

Save, logout and login.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1251090)